# Using google maps on ios

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I would like to create an application in which i can access google map on in. i already followed this [process](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start) and successfully run the program. but when i zoom the map, i experienced this kind of error.

2013-08-15 09:42:30.990 ATMBranchLocator[1277:c07] ClientParametersRequest failed, 1 attempts remaining (0 vs 5). Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1003 "A server with the specified hostname could not be found." UserInfo=0x1506bab0 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https ://clients4.google.com/glm/mmap, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https ://clients4.google.com/glm/mmap, NSLocalizedDescription=A server with the specified hostname could not be found., NSUnderlyingError=0x915dd20 "A server with the specified hostname could not be found."}

Please help me into this. I need to create this program only today.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your iOS device doesn't have internet connectivity. It will attempt to validate the API key you provide to GMSServices by pinging our servers. It also needs internet connectivity to download map data...

Comment: i've already figured out, it seems like, there is a problem in dragging the sdk on to the project even if i already checked the copy to folder something. my work around is, i opened the project folder then drag it there, refresh my xcode then drag it again there. it solved my problem.